# How to encode Times within Days in Multi-level Mixed Model in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I have the following experiment:

I tested 16 subjects on 4 different days with a (repeated) measurement every 20 minutes for a total of approximately 15 measurements/day.

I have about 4 time varying-predictors that could explain changes in Outcome.

I was thinking about coding something like this:

```r
library(nlme)

modelA <- lme(Outcome ~ predictor1 * time + predictor2 * time + 
                          predictor3 * time + predictor4 * time, 
              data = dataset, 
              random = ~ time / Day | ID, method = "ML", 
              na.action = na.omit, correlation = corAR1())
```

However, I can't find any theory anywhere to support this. Is there some explanation somewhere on how to code these kinds of Time/Day models?

The goal of having the 4 days was to have more data to fit the mixed models. All 4 days are in-situ uncontrolled conditions, monitoring the environment (Noise) surrounding the subjects...

I have asked a professor in charge of mixed model courses and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: "monitoring the environment (Noise) surrounding the subjects" It appears very unlikely that there is a linear relationship of this with time. You should probably use a non-parametric model for the time effect (i.e., a GAM-smoother) or possibly a cosinor model.

Comment: Noise is calculated as equivalent (average) over the cumulative duration... so it should be linear with time